# swift 2 convert int to numberFromString as String

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new in swift and I want to write the number with commas

```
NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("123456789")) as! String
```

I have error Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String'.
Any help please

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to write the number with commas". Can you show us the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, commas means the result will be "123,456,789"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
let myNumber = 123456789
var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(myNumber)!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the number of fractions with:

```
let numberToConvert: Int = 123456789
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

let convertedNumber = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(numberToConvert)
```

prints

```
"123456789.00"
```

If you want something like "123,456,789" then add following line after minimumFactionDigits

```
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
```

Comment: numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2 is really useful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var string= "7890"
var number = Int(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If u don't need to specify number of decimal places:

```
 var number: CGFloat = 98888.5555
 var string = "\(number)"
```